# Why nil cannot be matched in case/ecase?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

The following form

```
(let ((foo nil))
  (ecase foo
    (:bar 1)
    (:baz 2)
    (nil 3)))
```

throws error `NIL fell through ECASE expression`. The workaround for this seems to be to wrap `nil` case with parenthesis, like this:

```
(let ((foo nil))
  (ecase foo
    (:bar 1)
    (:baz 2)
    ((nil) 3))) ;; => 3
```

but why the first example doesn't work? Does unwrapped `nil` case have some special meaning?

Comment: you can also use `'nil`

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim But then, you also match `quote`, since `'nil` is reader syntax for `(quote nil)`, which in the context of a case means a match for either `quote` or `nil`.

Comment: @coredump thanks - true - I tried:`(let ((foo 'quote))
  (case foo
    (bar 1)
    (baz 2)
    (quote 'upps)('nil 3)))
;; returning UPPS
`  so there is solely `(nil)` for the case of `nil` for a correct match.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim : case items are not evaluated, thus quoting them makes no sense. Never use QUOTE in a CASE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each clause in `case` can be match a single item or a list of items, e.g. you can write:

```
(ecase foo
  (:bar 1) ;; match a specific symbol
  ((:baz :quux) 2)) ;; match either of these symbols
```

`NIL` is also the empty list in Lisp, and when it's used as the test in `case` this is how it's treated, so it never matches anything. Similarly, `T` and `OTHERWISE` are used to specify the default case, so you can't match them as single items. To match any of these, you need to put them in a list.

More technically, the [specification](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_case_.htm) says this about the keys in a clause:

> *keys*---a designator for a list of objects. In the case of case, the symbols `t` and `otherwise` may not be used as the keys designator. To refer to these symbols by themselves as keys, the designators `(t)` and `(otherwise)`, respectively, must be used instead.

and the definition of a [list designator](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_l.htm#list_designator) says:

> a designator for a list of objects; that is, an object that denotes a list and that is one of: a non-nil atom (denoting a singleton list whose element is that non-nil atom) or a proper list (denoting itself).

Notice that the case where a single atom is treated as a singleton list says "non-nil atom". That permits `NIL` to fall into the second case, where a proper list denotes itself. Otherwise, there would be no way to create a list designator for an empty list, since `NIL` would denote `(NIL)`.

You might argue that there's not much point in having an empty list of keys in `CASE`, since it will never match anything and the whole clause could just be omitted. This degenerate case is there for the benefit of automated code generation (e.g. other macros that expand into `CASE`), since they might produce empty lists, and these should be treated consistently with other list. It would be harder for them to make the generation of the clause conditional on whether there are any keys.

Comment: that makes total sense. Thank you for the explanation!